# What does ^= mean in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

I found this part of the code "^ =" in some old project, I saw how it changes state when I call "status ^ = YES;". Can someone explain to me what this is?

```
BOOL status = YES; 
status ^= YES;
```

Comment: I'd tend to say it's a XOR operator usually used for bits in Ints, not boolean, and done in the way of `a += b` like `a = a + b`. So `status = status ^ YES`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C

> The bitwise XOR (exclusive or) performs a logical XOR function, which is equivalent to adding two bits and discarding the carry. The result is zero only when we have two zeroes or two ones. XOR can be used to toggle the bits between 1 and 0. Thus `i = i ^ 1` when used in a loop toggles its values between 1 and 0.

So `status ^= YES` is a wiseass way of toggling between 1 and 0, aka YES and NO. Mere mortals would say `status = !status`.

Comment: The tricky part is the fact that it's still a bitwise operation, `BOOL status = 2` will mess it up.

Comment: @Sulthan I said it was wiseass. That means it’s the kind of thing a 65 year old C programmer would do just because a bool is actually an int. You know, like testing a numeric expression with `if` just because 0/nil is false. It’s bad style disguised as arch cleverness. But it sure saves a couple of machine cycles! When I was young that’s how we coded.